# Multicast to work on IPoIB with ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsan

My lab is running:

- ESXi, 6.5.0, 4887370
- OFED 1.8.2.5
- ConnectX-2 MHQH29C with 2.9.1000
- IS5035 switch with subnet manager

I followed the instructions here: [10Gb SFP+ single port = cheaper than dirt](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/10gb-sfp-single-port-cheaper-than-dirt.6893/page-9#post-145423)

I am able to get IPoIB working and all of the hosts can ping each other.

However, multicast is not working. How can I get multicast to work? It is preventing vSAN from working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking this doesn't answer your question... but if you're already running 6.5 build 4887370 (6.5a?) why don't you update to [6.5d](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/rn/vsphere-vcenter-server-650d-release-notes.html) ([VSAN 6.6](http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/vsan/66/vmware-virtual-san-66-release-notes.html)) or higher and say "[Goodbye Multicast](https://blogs.vmware.com/virtualblocks/2017/04/11/goodbye-multicast/)"?